# PHP number format doesn't allow jquery sum

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, number-formatting

I have a problem to do calculations with numbers in jquery. When the number is in the PHP number-format, jquery doesn't detect those numbers. Please find the  code and the screen-shot of the output. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  <tr  class="noBorder">
  <td><span class="circle">1A</span></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="amnt" value="<?php echo number_format($a1,2);?>"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr  class="noBorder">
  <td><span class="circle">4</span></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="amnt" id="4tax" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr  class="noBorder">
  <td><span class="circle">5A</span></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="amnt" id="5a" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr  class="noBorder">
  <td><span class="circle">7</span></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="7"  class="amnt"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr  class="noBorder">
  <td><span class="circle">7A</span></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="7a" class="amnt" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr  class="noBorder">
  <td>1A+4+5A+7+7A</td>
  <td><span class="circle">8A</span></td>
  <td>
<input type="text" id="8a" />
  </td>
  </tr>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".amnt").on("keydown keyup", function() {
        calculateSum();
    });
function calculateSum() {
    var sum2 = 0; 
    $(".amnt").each(function() {
        //add only if the value is number
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum2 += parseFloat(this.value);
            //$(this).css("background-color", "#FEFFB0");
        }

    });

}
```

Output:
**8A=1A+4+5A+7+7A**
[image]

Comment: _Please find the relevant part of the code..._ Please post the relevant code or highlight it :) BTW there is no such a thing like a PHP number

Comment: I  have highlighted the code :) I meant PHP number_format :)

Comment: Check the markup (rendered html) rather than the PHP to see what's happening.  Also, what happens if you change the `else if` to just an `else` (temporarily) and uncomment the commented code?

Comment: thank you. I will remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Please check this one:-***

```js
$(".amnt").on("keydown keyup", function() {
    calculateSum();
});
function calculateSum() {
var sum2 = 0; 
$(".amnt").each(function() {
    //add only if the value is number
    if (this.value.indexOf(',') > -1) { 
      sum2  += parseFloat(this.value.split(",").join(""));
    }else if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        sum2 += parseFloat(this.value);
        $("#sum").text(sum2).css("background-color", "#FEFFB0");
    }
});

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "text" class= "amnt" value = "8,133,231.17"><br/>
<input type = "text" class= "amnt" value = ""><br/>
<input type = "text" class= "amnt" value = ""><br/>
<div id = "sum"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`Javascript` can't handle numbers with `,` in it as thousands separator. It is not a number, it is a human-formatted string. Do as follows

```
<?php echo number_format($a1, 2, '.', '');?>
```

UPD. In js you can remove `,` with `this.value.replace(/,/g, "")` to remove commas:

```
parseFloat("12,233.12")
>12
parseFloat("12,233.12".replace(/,/g,""))
>12233.12
```

```js
$(".amnt").on("keydown keyup", function() {
        calculateSum();
    });
function calculateSum() {
    var sum2 = 0; 
    $(".amnt").each(function() {
        var thevalue = this.value.replace(/,/g,'');

        if (!isNaN(thevalue ) && thevalue .length != 0) {
            sum2 += parseFloat(thevalue);
            $("#sum").text(sum2).css("background-color", "#FEFFB0");
        }
    });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "text" class= "amnt" value = "8,133,231.17"><br/>
<input type = "text" class= "amnt" value = ""><br/>
<input type = "text" class= "amnt" value = ""><br/>
<div id = "sum"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i have tried to change sum2 += parseFloat((this.value).replace(",","")); But didn't work.

Comment: $(".amnt").each(function() { sum2 += parseFloat((this.value).replace(",",""));});
I did this. But didnt work

Comment: Please, comment when downvoting. Doesn't it sum as OP wishes to?

Comment: @shukshin.ivan  take care that when you edit some-one code, then check it will work properly. Otherwise don't touch please

Comment: @shukshin.ivan  it's OK, but take care in future.

Comment: @shukshin.ivan  your code is correct  too. +1. only thing that is you asked him to change both php and jquery,while i asked only one change in jquery

Answer (score 0):

I will advice you to display the numbers with Javascript instead of PHP. First set the value="" in your html

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    //use json_encode to make the php script readable by javascript
     var amntval = Number(<?php echo json_encode($a1,2);?>); 

    //display the value in the amnt field 
    $(".amnt").val(amntval.toLocaleString('en'));

    //now run your calculations
    $(".amnt").on("keydown keyup", function() {
        calculateSum();
    });
    function calculateSum() {
         var sum2 = 0; 
         $(".amnt").each(function() {
         //add only if the value is number
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum2 += parseFloat(this.value);
           //$(this).css("background-color", "#FEFFB0");
    }

});

}


});
```

This worked for me and I have not tested it with your codes but I believe it should work!